# Why I don't see the Dynamic methods in the On Value Changed () event/s?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is script is attached to a Canvas.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;

public class SettingsMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioMixer audioMixer;

    public void SetVolume(float volume)
    {
        audioMixer.SetFloat("Volume", volume);
    }

    public void SetQuality(int qualityIndex)
    {
        QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(qualityIndex);
    }
}
```

And then under it in the Hierarchy for example I have Graphics a DropDown ui.
And on the Graphics in the Inspector at the bottom in On Value Changed I dragged the Canvas over but then when I click on No Function > SettingsMenu I can see the SetQuality method but there should be also SetQuality at the top under Dynamic int and it's not there :

[image: No Dynamic int]

Same problem with the SetVolume method. 
And I had this Dynamic float/int before but they are not exist now.

Answer (score 0):

That indeed is weird, if you look closely in the inspector you see, the dropdown onValueChanged delegate doesn't take any arguments, [In your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQGVB.png)

So to see the dynamic invokations in the list, your methods parameters must match the dropdown onValueChanged delegate parameters, as you see [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaNfq.png)

This maybe a bug with your current unity version, or it probably could go away if  you restart the editor, if not, consider updating to a newer version.